# Spring Boot results in HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

My Spring Boot application runs, but when I access it in Postman, it only returns "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" for every function call. I've tried many fixes, to no avail.

**Folder structure**

[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa4kS.png)

**FlightPlannerApplication.java**

```
package com.bogen.FlightPlanner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FlightPlannerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlightPlannerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**AirportAPI.java**

```
package com.bogen.FlightPlanner.api;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
import com.bogen.FlightPlanner.model.Airport;
import com.bogen.FlightPlanner.service.AirportService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("AirportAPI")
public class AirportAPI {
    
    @Autowired
    private AirportService airportService;
    
    @GetMapping("/getAirports")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAirports() {
        try {
            List<Airport> airports = airportService.getAirports();
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Airport>>(airports, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**AirportServiceImpl.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.bogen.FlightPlanner.dao.AirportDAO;
import com.bogen.FlightPlanner.model.Airport;

@Service(value="airportService")
@Transactional
public class AirportServiceImpl implements AirportService {

    @Autowired
    AirportDAO airportDAO;
    
    @Override
    public List<Airport> getAirports() {
        List<Airport> airports = null;
        
        try {
            airports = airportDAO.getAirports();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return airports;
    }
}
```

And the **AirportDAOImpl.java** file is as you would expect, annotated with `@Repository` and containing an EntityManager annotated with `@PersistenceContext`.

Here is the console log:

```
2020-12-02 12:48:43.236  INFO 4452 --- [           main] c.b.F.FlightPlannerApplication           : Starting FlightPlannerApplication using Java 15.0.1 on DESKTOP-38S2QIU with PID 4452 (C:\Users\bogen\Downloads\FlightPlanner\target\classes started by bogen in C:\Users\bogen\Downloads\FlightPlanner)
2020-12-02 12:48:43.238  INFO 4452 --- [           main] c.b.F.FlightPlannerApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-02 12:48:43.552  INFO 4452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-12-02 12:48:43.562  INFO 4452 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-02 12:48:43.894  INFO 4452 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-02 12:48:43.901  INFO 4452 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-02 12:48:43.901  INFO 4452 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-12-02 12:48:43.973  INFO 4452 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/Project]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-02 12:48:43.973  INFO 4452 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 708 ms
2020-12-02 12:48:44.095  INFO 4452 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-02 12:48:44.123  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-02 12:48:44.162  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.23.Final
2020-12-02 12:48:44.263  INFO 4452 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/Project'
2020-12-02 12:48:44.265  INFO 4452 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-12-02 12:48:44.265  INFO 4452 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-12-02 12:48:44.268  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2020-12-02 12:48:44.272  INFO 4452 --- [           main] c.b.F.FlightPlannerApplication           : Started FlightPlannerApplication in 1.272 seconds (JVM running for 1.516)
2020-12-02 12:48:44.348  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-02 12:48:44.591  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-02 12:48:44.610  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-12-02 12:48:45.032  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-12-02 12:48:45.038  INFO 4452 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

And finally, the **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bogen</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlightPlanner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FlightPlanner</name>
    <description>Flight Planner project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The application runs indefinitely, as expected. The GET request from Postman goes to the URL: *http://localhost:8080/Project/AirportAPI/getAirports*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add spring-boot-starter-web dependency. spring-web is not enough. You need the Spring Boot wrapper with the autoconfiguration so that Spring MVC will be bootstrapped for you.

Comment: Thank you Paul! Can't believe it was so simple.

Comment: A lot of problems usually are that easy to solve, it's just most people don't post enough information for us to be able to disect the problem. So thank you for posting all that you did.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`spring-web` is not enough. You need the Spring Boot wrapper with the autoconfiguration so that Spring MVC will be bootstrapped for you.

You can also remove the `spring-web` dependency, as it will be pulled for you by the `spring-boot-start-web`.